# how to open a new cmd window using dosbox?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dosbox

Is there any way I can open a new cmd window from dosbox?
Cannot use `start` directly/indirectly.

Mounting c: drive and directly typing the path doesn't work too..

Neither `run` nor `execute` commands work.

There is no limitation is that cmd should be opened in new window, etc. Actually i am doing this to enter 2-3 string inputs. (where choice command is not applicable)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DOS is a single tasking OS, how can you run multiple windows on it? There's no start command in DOS either. If you're talking about the cmd.exe then it's not DOS

Comment: i agree with your statement but then i would like to say i just want to open a cmd window where the user can input and then the cmd window can be terminated.

Comment: if it's `cmd` (which is the Windows Command Prompt), [set /p](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) is what you look for. If it's `DOS` (the ancient "Disk Operating System") or an emulator like DOSbox, that wouldn't work. No idea if that works for DOSbox, but you can find a few things to try [here](http://www.ericphelps.com/batch/userin/index.htm)

Comment: dosbox is a DOS virtual machine/emulator. It's not related to cmd or DOS in any way

Answer (score 0):

Although DOS is a monotask system, multiple instances of DOSbox can coexist on the hosting OS, and they can communicate by shared files with one another.

I tried the following batch STARTDOS.CMD on my Windows10 system (it can run either in CMD window or as a service):

```
 @ECHO OFF 
 TITLE %0
 ECHO >C:\STARTDOS.REQ
:LOOP
 SLEEP 3
 IF NOT EXIST C:\STARTDOS.REQ GOTO :LOOP
 DEL C:\STARTDOS.REQ
 ECHO Starting another DOSbox ...
 START D:\APL\EMU\DOSBox\DOSBox.exe -userconf -noconsole
 GOTO :LOOP
```

This batch checks the existence of semaphore file C:\STARTDOS.REQ to start another DOSbox instance in a new cmd window.

In DOSbox configuration file I have `mount c C:\`

Now if I execute **ECHO >C:\STARTDOS.REQ** withing one DOSbox window, this will launch another DOSbox in its own cmd window.